# No JSON object could be decoded ,even when valid json in present in the file

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, file, dictionary

For converting dictionary element to Json and write to a file ,

```
with open(filename,'w') as f:
        if(os.stat(f).st_size == 0):
            json.dump(new_data, f)

        else:
                    data = json.load(f)
                    data.update(new_data)#adding a new dictionary 
                    json.dump(data, f)
```

i am able to write only one json to the file. When i want to read the exisiting file and then append another set of dictionary , i am unable to do .

Getting ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded tried

json.loads(f), json.load(f)

Comment: Strange, I wouldn't expect you to get `ValueError`, I'd expect `IOError: File not open for reading`. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: yes if i give open as w+ , i am getting ignored of file not open error , but every time a new json is written , even though a file exists in the same location. Printing data in the above code shows None. So issue is data = json.load(f) which is not happening

Comment: I can *guarantee* that `f`'s size will be 0 bytes, because any file opened in `'w'` mode is truncated to 0 bytes.

Comment: The code you posted is obviously not the code raising this exception - `os.stat()` takes a path, not a `file` object -, and even if you replace `os.stat(f)` with `os.stat(f.name)`, `st_size` will ALWAYS be zero here since a file opened in write mode is immediatly truncated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply read from the file first, if it exists. If it is already empty, or contains invalid JSON, or doesn't exist, initialize `data` to the empty `dict` (which is the identity element for the `update` method).

```
try:
    with open(filename) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
except (IOError, ValueError):
    data = {}
```

*Then* open the file in write mode to write the updated data.

```
data.update(new_data)
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

Comment: after json.dump(data) i would be having a json in the file , next time i need to read this json ,(which has one dictionary ) json.load() and add /append dict2 to the existing file , that is where i am facing the issue . Any help on this?

Comment: That's what this code does (at least, after adding the forgotten second argument to `json.dump`). It's not clear what you are actually doing with the data, though. Are you updating an object (`{foo:bar} + {hello: world} -> {foo:bar, hello:world}`), or adding an object to a array of objects (`[{foo:bar}] + {hello:world}] -> [{foo:bar}, {hello:world}]`)?